# I want to toggle between to functions

Tags: google-sheets

I want to make one button to turn something on and off for my pathfinder character sheet. At the moment I have two buttons, one for on and one for off but I want just one. I've googled it and asked people but no luck. Im using google sheets

```
function increment_aot() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Skills!D3').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Skills!D3').getValue() + 4);
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Attack!G24').setValue(10);
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G18').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G18').getValue() - 1);
}
function decrement_aot() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Skills!D3').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Skills!D3').getValue() - 4);
}
```

These are the two functions that I want the button I want to toggle between.

```
function test_increment_aot() {
  var counter =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Skills!J3');
  if (counter < 1) { 
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Skills!D3').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Skills!D3').getValue() + 4);
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Attack!G24').setValue(10);
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G18').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G18').getValue() - 1);

   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Skills!J3').setValue(1);
} else {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Skills!D3').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Skills!D3').getValue() - 4);
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Skills!J3').setValue(0)
}
}
```

Is what Ive tried but it didnt work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You need to access the value of the range `J3`

For this, use the method [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue):

```
function test_increment_aot() {
  var counter =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Skills!J3').getValue();
  ...
}
```